# Create a table with repeating header with iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to create a table with repeatingheaders like the image that I attached to my post.

I want to fill the first three columns on the left to the end of the table and then fill the second three columns on the right of the table.

I used one table with 6 columns as it shown on the page.I fetched the data from database based on date order and I want to place my data in the table like the picture.

I can create a the table with iText in java but I don't know how can I create a table with this style in with iText. please help me if it is possible.

[image: Table style]

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively straightforward.

First I made a class that represents a single data entry.

```
static class Record{
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public Record(String firstname, String lastname){
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getFirstname(){return firstname;}
    public String getLastname(){return lastname;}
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o instanceof Record){
            Record r = (Record) o;
            return r.firstname.equals(firstname) && r.lastname.equals(lastname);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I also made a method that randomly generates objects of this kind, using characters of The Simpsons.

```
private static Random RANDOM = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
public Record randomRecord(){
    String[] fn = {"Marge", "Homer", "Bart", "Lisa", "Nelson", "Apu", "Doris", "Seymour"};
    String[] ln = {"Bouvier", "Simpson", "Muntz", "Nahasapeemapetilan", "Skinner"};
    return new Record(fn[RANDOM.nextInt(fn.length)], ln[RANDOM.nextInt(ln.length)]);
}
```

The code to generate the table looks like this:

```
    List<Record> recordList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<17;i++)
        recordList.add(randomRecord());

    File outputFile = getOutputFile();
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputFile));
    Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);

    int numberOfItemsInFirstHalf = (int) Math.ceil(recordList.size() / 2.0);

    Table table = new Table(new float[]{0.16f, 0.16f, 0.16f, 0.16f, 0.16f, 0.16f});

    // header
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Number")).setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(74,189,172)));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Firstname")).setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(74,189,172)));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Lastname")).setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(74,189,172)));
    }

    // table
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfItemsInFirstHalf;i++){
        Record r0 = recordList.get(i);
        Record r1 = (i+numberOfItemsInFirstHalf) < recordList.size() ? recordList.get(i + numberOfItemsInFirstHalf) : null;

        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph((i + 1)+"")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(r0.getFirstname())));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(r0.getLastname())));

        if(r1 == null){
            table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")));
            table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")));
            table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")));
        }else{
            table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph((i + numberOfItemsInFirstHalf + 1)+"")));
            table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(r1.getFirstname())));
            table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(r1.getLastname())));
        }
    }

    layoutDocument.add(table);

    pdfDocument.close();
```

which generates the following PDF document:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.I tested your code but the the result is not match to my request. for example if I have 250 record, the records devided in two pages and the number are placed below each other not beside each other.In first page the last number is 53 and the first number of second page is 54 and it is wrong. I want to have 54th record in the first page just after that 53 in the second three columns on the right.

Comment: Yes, this code obviously does not take into account pagination. If you want that, you will need to keep track of where a table is broken up.
But the basic principle would be the same.

Comment: Thanks.Is there any method to find out where the table is broken up?

Comment: When adding an IElement to a document, you can ask the Renderer for its children. If a table is split, you would expect to see a SplitRenderer.

Comment: I searched through the intenet but i couldn't find any example which is used SplitRenderer. I am a newby and till now I used a simple structure of iText till now so I don't have any idea about SplitRenderer but I try my best.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get how do you want your table to be processed on split and supposed that you're in search for a two column layout. If that's the case, there is a predefined `ColumnDocumentRenderer` class for you. If set on Document instance it allows to layout the document content into columns.

So i defined the columns:

`Rectangle pageSize = pdfDocument.getDefaultPageSize();
        Rectangle[] areas = new Rectangle[2];
        areas[0] = new Rectangle(36, 36, ((float) pageSize.getWidth() / 2) - 35.75f, pageSize.getHeight() - 72);
        areas[1] = new Rectangle((float) pageSize.getWidth() / 2 - 0.25f, 36, ((float) pageSize.getWidth() / 2) - 35.75f , pageSize.getHeight() - 72);`

And then I applied the renderer on the Document instance:
`layoutDocument.setRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(layoutDocument, areas));`

The result on split looks that way:
[image]

The code in full:

```
    @Test
public void tableTest02() throws Exception {
    String outFileName = destinationFolder + "tableTest02.pdf";
    String cmpFileName = sourceFolder + "cmp_tableTest02.pdf";

    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));
    Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);


    Table table = new Table(3);
    table.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));

    Rectangle pageSize = pdfDocument.getDefaultPageSize();
    Rectangle[] areas = new Rectangle[2];
    areas[0] = new Rectangle(36, 36, ((float) pageSize.getWidth() / 2) - 35.75f, pageSize.getHeight() - 72);
    areas[1] = new Rectangle((float) pageSize.getWidth() / 2 - 0.25f, 36, ((float) pageSize.getWidth() / 2) - 35.75f , pageSize.getHeight() - 72);

    layoutDocument.setRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(layoutDocument, areas));
    // header
    for(int i=0;i<1;i++) {
        table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Number")).setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(74,189,172)));
        table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Firstname")).setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(74,189,172)));
        table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Lastname")).setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(74,189,172)));
    }

    // table
    for(int i=0;i<500;i++){

        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph((i + 1)+"")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Hello")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("World")));

    }

    layoutDocument.add(table);

    pdfDocument.close();

    Assert.assertNull(new CompareTool().compareByContent(outFileName, cmpFileName, destinationFolder, "diff"));
}
```

The tricky moment was to collapse table borders but increasing the width with 0.25f and moving the right column 0.25f on the left i achieved the borders to be placed one on the other.

Comment: I attached the picture to my first post which shows the style of  the table that I want.I uploaded the style that I want in following address again.https://ufile.io/uppi0. I want to have this style in every page for example the second page start from number 42 to 82 and so on.

Comment: 1) So that by  _repetitive_ header you mean that the header should be repeated only on the first page?

2) Suppost that 20 rows can be placed on a page. What is the output you expect: a) or b) ?
a)
1 11 \n
2 12 \n
...... \n
10 20 \n
PAGEBREAK
21 31 \n
22 32 \n
........ \n
30 40 \n

b)
1 21 \n
2 22 \n
...... \n
10 30 \n
PAGEBREAK
11 31 \n
12 32 \n
........ \n
20 40 \n

Comment: I mean in every page I have a table with these column: number, name, family, number, name, family. Then I want to fill them exactly like the picture that I attach and exact numbering that is shown in the picture and fill the table with this pattern(as shown in the picture) till the data are finished.In other word, I want to have 41 records in first page in the style that is shown in picture and 41 records in the second  page and so on.

Comment: Ok, so the code i provided in the answer will help you then.

Comment: No it didn't because it created one table with 3column not 6 column as I said and numbering the every single row. It didn't match to the style that I want at all.